# How to tell the number of solutions to a simultaeneous equation?

Tags: linear-algebra

> **How many solutions are there to the following simultaeneous equations?**:
>   $$
> \begin{align}
> x - 2y + 3z = 1\\
> 2x + 2y - z = 4\\
> 4x - y + 5z = 6
> \end{align}
> $$

How can I know the number of solutions that there are?

EDIT: 
I have found z = 0, y = 2/7, x = 11/7 as solutions but the answers I have say that there are infinite solutions. How can one deduce this?

Please note that I am a high school student and am unable to understand advanced mathematics.

Comment: This kind of problem is usually the _very first thing_ a linear algebra textbook discusses. So it is difficult to imagine how you can know enough to have tagged the question "linear algebra" and still not know the answer already. Please extend the question with some discussion of what you already know, such that we can give an answer that addresses the knowledge you're actually searching.

Comment: From rearranging, I can find several sets of solutions but the answers say there are an infinite set and I do not know how to deduce this.

Comment: If you have a solution attempt that gives wrong results (or several solutions attempt that give _different_ results), **edit your question to show those attempts**. That will allow people who answer to figure out more precisely what the mistake or misunderstanding you need to correct is.

Comment: My apologies, I have done this.

Comment: There are only three possibilities for the number of solutions to a system of linear equations: none, one, or an infinite number. If, as you say, you can find several solutions, then you know that it’s not the first two possibilities.

Comment: @CasperC. Your above solution $(x,y,z)=(11/7,2/7,0)$ is wrong: take the second equation. Then you have $2x+2y-z=22/7+4/7-0=26/7\neq 4$.

Answer (score 3):

Find the [augmented matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Augmented_matrix) corresponding to the system of equations, then, using [Gaussian elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination), manipulate it into [row echelon form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row_echelon_form). This will give you information about the number of solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: multiplying the first equation by $-2$ and addin g to the second we get
$$6y-7z=2$$ (I)
multiplying the first by $-4$ and adding to the third we get
$$7y-7z=2$$ (II)
can yuo finish?
multiplying (I) by $-1$ and adding to (II):
we get $$y=0$$ and $$z=-\frac{2}{7}$$
i have got $$x=\frac{13}{7}$$ Make a Control if my solution is right

Comment: Thanks. The answers I have say there are infinitely many solutions. Are they wrong/how can that be?

Comment: @CasperC. If the system matrix is invertible, then there is one and only one solution.

Comment: Pardon, but what is the meaning of 'invertible' in this context?

Comment: I made a Control that your solution is correct. Caspar's solution above is not correct.

Comment: thank you for this Information Dietrich!

Answer (score 0):

Write the system as $Ax=b$ with the matrix
$$
A=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & -2 & 3 \cr 2 & 2 & -1 \cr 4 & -1 & 5 \end{pmatrix}.
$$
Since $\det(A)\neq 0$ we can form the inverse, so that there is a unique solution $x=A^{-1}b$. Indeed, $x=A^{-1}(Ax)=A^{-1}b=(13/7,0,-2/7)^T$. In general, use row-echelon form, and see how many elements your field $K$ has (such equations do make sense over finite fields, too).

Answer (score 0):

The general result  for a square matrix of dimension $n$ is the following:

> - If the matrix has maximal rank $r=n$, there is exactly one solution.
> - If the matrix has rank $r<n$, and if the augmented matrix has the same rank, the solution are an *affine subspace* of dimension $n-r$.
> - If the matrix has rank $r<n$, and if the augmented matrix has rank $r'>r$, there is no solution.